# Drop DynamoDB if it exists

Tags: docker, makefile, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to setup dynamodb in my local using docker. I wish to control is initialization by using makefile. Here is the makefile I am using

```
TABLE_NAME="users"

create_db:
    @aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 create-table \
    --table-name $(TABLE_NAME) \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=userID,AttributeType=N \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=userID,KeyType=HASH \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 >> /dev/null;

drop_db: check_db
    check_db; if [test $$? -eq 1] then \
        @aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 delete-table --table-name $(TABLE_NAME); \
    fi

check_db:
    -@aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 describe-table --table-name $(TABLE_NAME);
```

AWS does not give **DROP IF EXISTS** functionality like MYSQL, so I am trying to use output of describe table to check the presence of the table. However getting the following error

```
check_db; if [test $? -eq 1] then \
        @aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 delete-table --table-name "requests"; \
    fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `check_db; if [test $? -eq 1] then     @aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 delete-table --table-name "requests"; fi'
make: *** [drop_db] Error 2
```

I am new to makefile and cannot figure out how to solve the error. What is wrong in the above makefile? And is there any better way to check presence of dynamo table

Answer (score 2):

It's not a `Makefile` issue, it's a syntax error in your shell script. Basically you need a semicolon before `then`.

```
$ false; if [test $? -eq 1] then echo foo; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

You also need to decide to either use `[` or `test`, as the current syntax is also incorrect.

```
$ false; if [test $? -eq 1]; then echo foo; fi

Command '[test' not found, did you mean:

...
```

Working version:

```
$ false; if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo foo; fi
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made this workaround to mimic DROP IF EXISTS functionality with dynamoDB

```
drop_db: check_db
    @if grep -q -i "active" a.out ; then \
        aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 delete-table --table-name $(TABLE_NAME) >> /dev/null; \
        rm a.out; \
    fi

check_db:
    @aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 describe-table --table-name $(TABLE_NAME) --output text &> a.out;
```